# How to describe other unknown properties in JSDoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

For function below how to express that parameter `foo` must have property `bar` of type `number` but it can also have other properties.

I'd expect that `???` in snippet below can be replaced with meaningful description.

```js
/**
 * @param {{bar: number, ???}} foo
 * @return {{bar: number, ???}} parameter `foo` with incremented property `bar`
 */
function fn(foo) {
    const { bar, ...rest } = foo
    console.log('bar', bar)
    console.log('other unknown properties', rest)

    foo.bar++
    return object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
/**
 * 
 * @param {{bar: number, [p:string]:any}} foo
 * @return {{bar: number, [p:string]:any}}
 */
function fun(foo) {
  const { bar, ...rest } = foo
  console.log('bar', bar)
  console.log('other unknown properties', rest)

  foo.bar++
  return foo
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add link to JSDoc documentation (jsdoc.app)? I can't find it there. It seems related to Typescript - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#type.

Comment: Flow seems to use same syntax as well (https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-objects-as-maps) however my IDE rejects it as invalid syntax.

Comment: @czerny Yes, it is related to TypeScript. And works great in VSCode.